# durandal.js - is it possible to load view specific css on demand with the view?

Tags: css, single-page-application, durandal

I have recently begun working on a SPA app that uses Durandal.js.  We have several views and models which are composed/loaded at different times into the app.

For example: MyFavorites.js + MyFavorites.html

Is there a way to somehow have durandal "link" a view to a css file (maybe MyFavorites.css in this case) so that it could get it as needed and potentially take advantage of caching?  I could put a  or  tag directly in my html file, but am under the impression that it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Durandal doesn't have anything specifically for this. However, there is a require.js css loader plugin which you could use from one of your js modules which are associated with the functionality. I think there are some "gotchas" with doing this, but it's worth looking into if you really want dynamic css injection.

Comment: Apart from the require.js css loader plugin, does anybody use any other method? I usually minify all my CSS into a single base file and include it in my index.html, but it would be more convenient to have my css loaded with modules only.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a plugin. You can use it for Durandal 2.0.

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return {
        loadCss : function (fileName) {
            var cssTag = document.createElement("link")
            cssTag.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
            cssTag.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
            cssTag.setAttribute("href", fileName)
            cssTag.setAttribute("class", "__dynamicCss")

            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssTag)
        },
        removeModuleCss: function () {
            $(".__dynamicCss").remove();

        }
    };
});
```

And you can use it as below in your viewmodel.

```
define(['plugins/cssLoader'], function (cssLoader) {
    var ctor = function () {
        this.compositionComplete =  function () {
            cssLoader.loadCss("sample.css");
            cssLoader.loadCss("sample2.css");


        };
        this.deactivate =  function () {
            cssLoader.removeModuleCss();
        }
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why placing an id or class on the anchor tag of the view is "bad practice" (CSSlist will shout at you for ids, but I think that's silly); it seems like a pretty elegant solution that uses the cascading that css provides for you to use. I think this is the approach taken dynamically by [Head JS](http://headjs.com/). You might look into that but I'm not sure how well it would play with Require JS. In any case, the manual approach should work just fine. The only thing you don't get is lazy-loading of the relevant css.

Another approach (that can be seen in the Knockout samples included with Durandal now) is to place a `<style type='text/css'>...</style>` section at the top of your view html. That gives you lazy-loading, at the cost of not having your css in separate files.

If your custom view styles need to apply to more than one view, you'd probably go with the former approach to keep things DRY (using classes instead of ids, of course).

Also, take a look at [this](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css) from the RequireJS docs.

Comment: Placing `<script type='text/css'>...</script>` directly in HTML is not generally recommended as it does not allow you to keep your HTML, CSS separate, which is the standard practice nowadays. Also you would not be able to use common CSS styles anymore, as you would have to include/ maintain the same CSS in every HTML file it is needed in. Not to mention how long some of the styles can get sometimes.